# What causes Azure Mobile Service MS account login to throw Operation could not be completed?

Tags: azure, authentication, token, azure-mobile-services

I have a simple service with a simple login using Live Authentication token that works *most* of the time. However, sometimes this line:

```
MobileServiceUser loginResult = await MobileService.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(token);
```

throws a bunch of *WebExceptions* and *MobileServiceInvalidOperationException*. The message I receive is

```
Operation could not be completed. ()
```

This bedazzles me a bit. Usually this prohibits login for like a few minutes. Having a reconnect button in the App that allows me to retry connecting will eventually let me in. However, since other clients are able to login (running the same software), this is really weird.

[edit] The issue emerged again, so here's more data

This is from the request sent by MobileService.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(token);

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: '', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: some longish installation id
  X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: some longish app id
  Accept: application/json
  User-Agent: ZUMO/1.0
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.0.0.10211; arch=Win32NT; version=1.0.20324.0)
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.0.0.10211; arch=Win32NT; version=1.0.20324.0)
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 420
}}
```

And the response:

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Length: 0
}}
```

Comment: Can you get any network captures to get more information on what can be going on?

Comment: Problem is that this is rather rare in general (and seems occasional). I think it MIGHT have something to do with rapid logins (i.e. restarting the app a lot). Today I had a period of like 2 hours in which I ran into this issue 3 times. Each "downtime" only took like 2-3min. I will try to have network capture on if I can run into it again. I was merely wondering whether there's a limit to logins per user or something I should be aware of or whether this is random issue.

Comment: I added some of the stuff I get back from the mobile service here. And this happens like rarely but when it's down it's down. Any idea what could possibly cause this? NotFound is a weird code to get "sometimes" :)

Comment: In the request object you showed here the `RequestUri` property is empty. Is it really empty (which would indicate a problem in the client), or did you remove it before posting it here? If the latter, can you post the name of your mobile service so we can look at the internal logs to see if they show something?

Comment: I didn't remove it. This indeed is suggestive of a problem with the client. It's very weird though as there are no async calls running so it should never be null. I'll keep looking into it. The rarity of it suggests a concurrency issue though.